# Android GPS Grouping

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

Currently I'm in the planning/research phase for a final year college project I will be starting soon.

I want to make an android application focused on GPS/Tracking. The aim is to group together users on different devices. One user can generate a password which then can be used by other users which will then create a group. Anyone in this group can then see each others locations on google maps.

My question is what would be needed to create such an app? I have no experience in android development, I have a basic enough understanding of Java and Python.

From my own understanding I believe I would need Google Maps API, a server and a database.

Any articles/tutorials or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From Android side:**

- For acquiring GPS location you may want to use `GoogleApiClient`. This will give you good location results even if GPS won't be available in certain location because it also uses Wi-Fi for localizing and it has some other cool options.
  Check out this tutorial:
  http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/
- To handle connection to the server you may be interested in using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) or at least [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html). These are libraries which are helpful in making requests to your server.
- For map displaying you can use `Google Maps` or `OpenStreetMap`.

**From both sides:**

- In order to send something to the server and receive the response you may want to use some serialization tool. Consider communicating using JSON and using for example, [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) for that purpose. There are many tutorials for using this on the web. For example: http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/

**From server side:**

- Check out [Spring Boot Framework](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/). It's really powerful framework. It may be too much for starters but it's good to know it anyway. It will give you a possibility to make server with easy to maintenance code. You can just make a method and annotate it with `@RequestMapping("/players")`.
- [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) will give you possibility to build type safe SQL queries. Although, it's not necessary to have it, it will make things easier.
- Although it'll probably be small application, you may be interested in using some database connection pool. For example: [HikariCP](https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/)
- Database: You have to choose your database engine. I'd recommend using [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) with [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/install/) plugin because by using them you can for example, easily calculate distance from one person to another. It will handle the curvature of the earth for you. Generally, it's useful for storing location data.

You can make everything alive on your computer or you can use one of the cloud computing service providers. For example, [Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/) provides EC2 instances and relational databases like PostgreSQL and they give you free tier, so you can use their services for free with limited usage and for limited time. They also are friendly to students. Check out [GitHub Student Developer Pack](https://education.github.com/pack/offers).

Comment: Hi @Defozo thanks for your detailed answer, I will have a look into all of these. Would my method of connecting devices through a randomly generated password by efficent for what I'm trying to achieve or would there a better approach to connecting devices to see each others location?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you're trying to achieve. What's the purpose of sharing location with the other users? Can they be connected by sharing links? Or the password needs to be passed in real life?

Comment: I want that a person can go onto the app and create a group, the person can then give the password to the group to their friends which then can join the group. We people join the group their locations will then show up on the map and people can be tracked. For example if your out with friends and get lost you can go onto the app and see their location to find them again. My plan was that if you create a group it will generate a random password/key that then can be used by other users to connect with one another. Just seeing would this be a poor approach or would there be better ones?

Comment: I'm not user experience specialist but I guess your approach is generally OK. However, consider making links to your groups. So that you can easily send them to your friends and they can share their location without typing in the password but just by clicking the link. You can even make some registration to your service so that users can invite each other within the app. But don't make it too complicated for you to write the program. Start with something easy and then add more features.

Comment: hey @defozo , thats a good idea. I will start off with something simple to begin with anyways and work my way from there. You've been more than helpful, much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. If you find my answer helpful, please accept it :)